# Как в Laravel 5.5 использовать аутентификацию и автризацию только для админки?

Tags: laravel, laravel5

Необходимо в проекте на Laravel 5.5 сделать админку, которая будет доступна по путь site.domaine/admin. Развенул авторизацию "из коробки" согласно инструкции http://laravel.su/docs/5.4/authentication и пока она распространяется на весь сайт. Т.е. site.domaine/login, site.domaine/logout и т.д. А необходимо настроить проект так, что бы все это было внутри site.domaine/admin, т.е. site.domaine/admin/login, site.domaine/admin/logout и т.д. Подскажите как вынести все это на URL админки - /admin/*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

роутеры, отвечающие за админку вынести в группу с авторизацией

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

   # роутеры сайта

   Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
      # роутеры админки
   })
})
```